# Turning Off Car On Shabbat

Tags: melacha-creative-work

If one makes it home after sunset on Erev Shabbath, are they allowed to turn the car off? Being that they’ll be breaking the melachah of Mechabeh?

Comment: Hard to answer. Mainly because arriving home after sunset has already broken many melachot.

Comment: Why should he be allowed to turn the car off?

Comment: If you wanted to shut it off because you were afraid of thieves, could that be enough reason, analogous to blowing out a candle?

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to extinguish a fire due to fear of thieves. You're just exempt from a sin offering @Mike

Comment: Absolutely not. You have to pull over before Sabbath starts and park your car. I once had to walk two hours after getting stuck in traffic. Only exception might be if you are in a dangerous area. But you still can't turn your car off.